# Google spreadsheet publish as Atom

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, rss, atom-feed

I am trying to publish a Google spreadsheet as an RSS feed using Google Chrome. When I go to File → Publish to web and the go to Get a link to the published data, the Atom/RSS feed is not displayed.

When I tried to use my personal gmail account, this feature is visible but when I use the business one it does not work. Also please note that I am the admin of the account so I don't think it is an issue of rights.

Can you tell me how to publish it as an Atom/RSS feed, please?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have built-in support for RSS feeds by default, but google have developed an extension. You can add this one:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd
```

Comment: But the problem is within the Google Business side as the Personal gmail account works perfectly. And Also I can't find the RSS feed icon